# FasterXML Object to JSON with specific Casing

Tags: json, fasterxml

I am trying to use a REST web service that fronts a SOAP service. In order for this to work correctly, I have to send the correct case for the XML tags in my JSON message to the REST service.

Here is what they want:

```
{"mappingSSNValidation":{"Group":{"InSSN":"123456789"}}}
```

Here is what I am able to created:

```
{"mappingSSNValidation":{"group":{"inSSN":"123456789"}}}
```

Class definitions:

```
public class Group {
    protected String InSSN = null;
    //Public getters and setters
}
public class MappingSSNValidation {
    protected Group group = new Group();
    //Public getters and setters.
}
public class MyRequest {
    protected MappingSSNValidation mappingSSNValidation = new MappingSSNValidation();
    //Public getters and setters.
}
MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
request.getMappingSSNValidation().getGroup().setInSSN("123456789");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
mapper.writeValueAsString(request);
```

So my question is this: How do I get the Object name as the wrapper instead of the variable name? But this can only occur for the Group name. For the variables within group I want the variable name used.

I would think there is an annotation which I could use for this but I can't find one that works. I have tried the @JsonRootName on the Group class and that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

By using the @JsonProperty above definition of the variable, you can accomplish this.

```
public class MappingSSNValidation {
    @JsonProperty("Group")
    protected Group group = new Group();
    //Public getters and setters.
}
```